# Unable to detect ov5640 in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm trying to interface ov5640 with Raspberry Pi, so the first thing I need to do is making ov5640 getting detect and show up under i2c device nodes, so for that I need to add dts file, so I took the reference of ov5647 dts structure and created ov5640 dts structure, here I did not changed that much compared to ov5647 dts,
changes did in ov5647 dts file compared to ov5647:

```
 1. ov5647 is replaced with ov5640
 2. reg address is replaced with 3c
```

I compiled these dts file and copied to /boot/overlays/ and rebooted,
even though ov5640 is connected and compiled dts files are present still ov5640 is not getting detcted.

ov5640.dtsi

```
cam_node: ov5640@3C {
    compatible = "ovti,ov5640";
    reg = <0x36>;
    status = "disabled";

    clocks = <&cam1_clk>;

    avdd-supply = <&cam1_reg>;
    dovdd-supply = <&cam_dummy_reg>;
    dvdd-supply = <&cam_dummy_reg>;

    rotation = <0>;
    orientation = <2>;

    port {
        cam_endpoint: endpoint {
            clock-lanes = <0>;
            data-lanes = <1 2>;
            clock-noncontinuous;
            link-frequencies =
                /bits/ 64 <297000000>;
        };
    };
};
```

ov5640-overlay.dts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
// Definitions for OV5647 camera module on VC I2C bus
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";

    i2c_frag: fragment@0 {
        target = <&i2c_csi_dsi>;
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";

            #include "ov5640.dtsi"

            vcm: ad5398@c {
                compatible = "adi,ad5398";
                reg = <0x0c>;
                status = "disabled";
                VANA-supply = <&cam1_reg>;
            };
        };
    };

    csi_frag: fragment@1 {
        target = <&csi1>;
        csi: __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            brcm,media-controller;

            port {
                csi_ep: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&cam_endpoint>;
                    data-lanes = <1 2>;
                };
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&i2c0if>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@3 {
        target = <&i2c0mux>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    reg_frag: fragment@4 {
        target = <&cam1_reg>;
        __overlay__ {
            startup-delay-us = <20000>;
        };
    };

    clk_frag: fragment@5 {
        target = <&cam1_clk>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            clock-frequency = <25000000>;
        };
    };

    __overrides__ {
        rotation = <&cam_node>,"rotation:0";
        orientation = <&cam_node>,"orientation:0";
        media-controller = <&csi>,"brcm,media-controller?";
        cam0 = <&i2c_frag>, "target:0=",<&i2c_vc>,
               <&csi_frag>, "target:0=",<&csi0>,
               <&reg_frag>, "target:0=",<&cam0_reg>,
               <&clk_frag>, "target:0=",<&cam0_clk>,
               <&cam_node>, "clocks:0=",<&cam0_clk>,
               <&cam_node>, "avdd-supply:0=",<&cam0_reg>;
        vcm = <&vcm>, "status=okay",
              <&cam_node>,"lens-focus:0=", <&vcm>;
    };
};

&cam_node {
    status = "okay";
};

&cam_endpoint {
    remote-endpoint = <&csi_ep>;
};
```

can anyone give some direction to solve this issue?

**Edited 1:
Procedure I followed to add ov5640**

1. The kernel version I'm using and compiling is 5.15.70-v7l+
2. to add ov5640, I added device tree files  ov5640.dtsi and ov5640-overlay.dts to **path/to/kernel_source/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/**
3. To include these files in compilation I added **"ov5647.dtbo"** to **Makefile**
   present in **path/to/kernel_source/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/**
4. know after dealing with dts, I compiled and installed the modules

sudo make modules_install

and copied generated dtb and dtbo files to **/boot/overlays/**

```
cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb /boot/
cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/overlays/
cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/overlays/
cp arch/arm/boot/zImage /boot/kernel-image.img
```

and I added **kernel=kernel-image.img**   in  **/boot/config.txt** and powered off the Raspberry Pi.

5. ov5640 camera is connected to MIPI interface and powered on the Raspberry Pi
6. After powering on I used this command to list the devices

   $ls /dev/i2c-*

   /dev/i2c-1 /dev/i2c-20 /dev/i2c-21

as shown ov5640 is not get detected
but when I do this with ov5647

```
 $ls /dev/i2c-*
 /dev/i2c-0 /dev/i2c-1 /dev/i2c-10 /dev/i2c-20 /dev/i2c-21 /dev/i2c-22
```

I had noted that when ov5647.dtsi and ov5647-overlay.dts is not compiled, ov5647 is not getting detcted.
the result is this

```
 $ls /dev/i2c-*
 /dev/i2c-1 /dev/i2c-20 /dev/i2c-21
```

but when I include ov5647.dtsi and ov5647-overlay.dts ov5647 getting detected

```
 $ls /dev/i2c-*
 /dev/i2c-0 /dev/i2c-1 /dev/i2c-10 /dev/i2c-20 /dev/i2c-21 /dev/i2c-22
```

**Edit 2 : Loading ov5640 driver dynamically**
I had loaded ov5640 driver dynamically the I got error

```
   $sudo insmod ov5640.ko
   insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ov5640.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

and at dmesg this what I got

```
    [   65.843312] ov5640: Unknown symbol v4l2_async_unregister_subdev (err -2)
[   65.843536] ov5640: Unknown symbol v4l2_async_register_subdev_sensor (err -2)
[   65.843873] ov5640: Unknown symbol v4l2_fwnode_endpoint_parse (err -2)
```

and  I'm getting the same error when dtbo  files of ov5647 is removed

from /boot/overlays/ov5647.dtbo and ov5647 mipi module is connected and tried to load the driver

```
   $sudo insmod ov5640.ko
   insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ov5647.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

dmesg log

```
   [  124.565887] ov5647: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  124.566475] ov5647: Unknown symbol v4l2_async_unregister_subdev (err -2)
[  124.566706] ov5647: Unknown symbol v4l2_async_register_subdev_sensor (err -2)
[  124.566766] ov5647: Unknown symbol v4l2_fwnode_device_parse (err -2)
[  124.567068] ov5647: Unknown symbol v4l2_fwnode_endpoint_parse (err -2)
```

but when I include ov5647 dts files /boot/overlays/ov5647.dtbo
and try to to load i got this

```
   [   53.932188] ov5647: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
   [   53.990576] ov5647 10-0036: Consider updating driver ov5647 to match on endpoints
```

and I'm able stream video

Note: both ov5647 and ov5640 drivers are dynamic modules

so from above result I'm thinking that the problem is with dts files as ov5647 shown same error as ov5640 while loading the driver, when dtbo file of ov5647 is removed.

Comment: You make no mention of configuring and building the kernel to include the ov5640 driver.  So perhaps that is what is missing?  Most PC distros will automatically download and install needed drivers (assuming an internet connection), whereas an embedded system typically requires a rebuild to support a new device.

Comment: @sawdust so do I need to compile whole kernel now?

Comment: "*so do I need to compile whole kernel now?*" -- How would I know? You have provided *zero* details of the kernel that you're using now.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for asking I had shared entire process I had followed can please look into it

Comment: Looks like you only edited and compiled the DT, which only informs the kernel of the hardware configuration. You still do not mention how you obtained your kernel image. You do not mention any changes to the kernel's build configuration, e.g. adding the OV5640 driver. Such a driver can be built as part of the kernel image or as a loadable module.  Use a kernel `make menuconfig` to add the OV5640 driver to the kernel build.  Learn to review the boot log (not the **/dev** directory) for outcomes.

Comment: @sawdust I'm using both ov5640 and ov5647 modules as dynamic modules and loading after boot up through terminal. can you check the post again to see the errors

Comment: Do you configure /boot/config.txt to load the overlay?

Comment: If you change `sudo insmod ov5640.ko` to `sudo modprobe ov5640` it should load the module and its dependencies (assuming the `ov5640` module was installed by `make modules_install`). But the `ov5640` module should get loaded automatically if the module has been installed and the overlay has been loaded.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks it worked adding `dtovrelay=ov5640` to `/boot/config.txt` worked it got detected as i2c , but when I try to load the driver using `sudo  modprobe ov5640` I got thsi error, in dmesg `ov5640-probe of 10-003c failed with error -2`

Comment: one more thing I noticed is even ov5640 is connected to MIPI interface, i2c nodes are created but for ov5647 that is not the case i2c nodes are being created only when ov5647 is connected

Comment: The error -2 (`-ENOENT`) is probably due to missing/incorrect properties in the device tree node. See "Documentation/devicetree/bindings/media/i2c/ov5640.txt". In your ov5640.dtsi file the `clock-names` property is missing (should be `clock-names = "xclk";`) and the `DOVDD-supply`. `AVDD-supply` and `DVDD-supply` property names are spelled incorrectly (they should not be all lower case).

Comment: @IanAbbott that error was gone present `ov5640:probe of 10-003c failed with error -121` is  throwing and and before that the error I'm getting  `ov5640 10-003c: ov5640_check_chip_id: failed to read chip identifier`

Comment: error -121 is `-EREMOTEIO`.

Comment: You could turn debug messages on in the i2c_bcm2835 module for more I2C diagnostic information: `echo 1 > sudo tee /sys/module/i2c_bcm2835/parameters/debug` (replace `echo 1` with `echo 2` or `echo 3` for progressively more debug messages, or with `echo 0` to turn them off).

Comment: The i2c_bcm2835 module will return the `-EREMOTEIO` error for an I2C transfer if the slave failed to acknowledge the I2C address. See bit 8 of the BSC S register on page 31 of [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) and the `bcm2835_i2c_xfer()` and `bcm2835_i2c_isr()` functions in "drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-bcm2835.c".

Comment: Are you sure that I2C slave address 0x36 is correct? You have `cam_node: ov5640@3C {` with `reg = <0x36>;`. The driver will use the I2C address from the `reg` property, which is inconsistent with the node's unit address `3C`. Perhaps you should use `reg = <0x3C>;`?

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks It worked finally video nodes were created